# Can we overlay a WPF element by another?

Tags: wpf, label, overlay

I've this situation:

A label placed in Footer Cell of a RadGridView doesn't have sufficient width available in its container for displaying  its full text.

Is it possible by any ways to have the label cross its container boundaries and show full text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The space given to any element depends on the parent control or Panel that contains it, as well as its Width, Height, Horizontal and VerticalAlignment, and Margin. Normally you can manipulate some combination of these directly to change overlapping behavior but by using a DataGrid control you've given up a lot of that control since things like ColumnSpan are set up by the control internally. You could try setting negative Margin values and changing the Panel.ZIndex but I doubt those will help.

The best solution I can recommend without more detail is to use TextWrapping or TextTrimming to avoid ugly clipping, maybe in combination with a ToolTip showing the full text.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. Do you have any idea how- if we can use ToolTip to display instead of Label inside the cell of datagrid footer? A ToolTip which can work independently and without mouse hover?

Comment: ToolTip uses the same display mechanism as Popup so you can use that if you want to display something independent of the layout system but with manual control over opening and closing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can either set `ClipToBounds=False` to allow it to expand outside its area, or set `TextWrapping=Wrap` to allow the text to wrap.

EDIT: Forgot `ClipToBounds` is only honored in the Canvas control, so wrap your label in a `Canvas` and set `ClipToBounds=False` and it should work.

Comment: Just remembered `ClipToBounds` only works for the `Canvas` control. Try wrapping your Label control in a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay any WPF element by another anytime. Only place where it fails is the WebBrowser control .The WPF WebBrowser has not been improved a single bit from WinForms WebBrowser. It is still the same simple activex control. However, you can bypass even that with a tooltip control.

Comment: Can you please put an example?

Comment: This problem isn't unique to the WebBrowser control. It happens with any interop content (WinForms, GDI, etc.) due to problems with compositing multiple Hwnds.

Comment: I guess WebBrowser control is out of context of my problem here. All I need is to overlay a simple Label.